# Is there a good protocol for bilateral decortication in rodents?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, experimental-design, cognition

I was thinking about using bilateral decortication in rodents (preferentially mice) to study the roles of certain brainstem areas in cognitive tasks in the absence of cortex. However almost all studies I could find with bilaterally decorticate rodents date back to at least the 1980s if not older. Is there a specific reason for this? Also, do you guys know of any relatively recent protocol for bilateral decortication in rodents?

Comment: Probably seen as a bit ethically questionable these days, without a particularly keen need/reasoning. Also techniques are preferred to be able to *temporarily* turn parts of the brain on and off, for example with optogenetics, DREADDs, etc.

Comment: @BryanKrause - this is akin to answer in comment. Insert a few links here and there and (at least) I would be happy with this answer. Otherwise you might wish to delete the comment?